# Ubuntu is using QWERTY keyboard shortcuts instead of Dvorak

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I type in Dvorak and today I updated from Ubuntu 18 to 21. Now, when I try to copy, cut or paste text in programs like Sublime Text or the terminal, I can only do so by using Qwerty shortcuts. This is no good as I'm used to Dvorak shortcuts.

So if I want to copy, I'd normally press Ctrl I. But now I have to press Ctrl C.

I think it's a new feature of Ubuntu 20 or something. They must have decided that people who use Dvorak prefer to use the original Qwerty keyboard shortcuts which are conveniently positioned (e.g. Ctrl: C-Copy, V-Paste).

But I don't find it convenient. So how do I get the Dvorak keyboard shortcuts back?

Comment: Do you mean Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu 20.04, and Ubuntu 21.04?  Please edit your question with the actual version numbers of the Ubuntu versions you are referencing

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem doesn't happen with the English (Dvorak, alt, intl.) keyboard layout. So I guess I'll use this instead of English (Dvorak).

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue as well. On Xubuntu 22.04, I was able to fix this by setting the keyboard on a per-user basis to Dvorak, but leaving the system default at English (US).

You can reset the system default using dpkg-reconfigure:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Then change the keyboard for each user to Dvorak using the graphical Keyboard utility.

UPDATE: I had both Dvorak and Qwerty options in my user account when I did this, and I discovered after posting that this fixed shortcuts in some applications but not others for me. I then removed the Qwerty option on the user end and now all applications use Dvorak shortcuts.

I added the Qwerty option back and now I seem to be getting Dvorak shortcuts all the time in all applications, even if I switch to Qwerty!

This works for me because I primarily use Dvorak and only need to switch to Qwerty if someone else needs to type. But it's an odd behavior for sure, and may not be consistent. More reboots and switches back-and-forth will be required to know for sure.